# strcpy access violation writing to a struct variable

Tags: c++, arrays, string, struct, strcpy

I have a struct called record which contains key, value pair:

```
struct Record{
    char* key=new char();
    TYPE value=NULL;
    Record(){
        key = "default";
        value = 10;
    }
    Record(const char* key_, TYPE value_){
        strcpy(key, key_);

        value = value_;
    }
    const Record<TYPE>& operator=(const Record<TYPE>& other){
        key = other.key;
        value = other.value;
        return *this;
    }
};
```

Also, I have a class "SimpleTable" which contains an array of those records:

```
class SimpleTable:public Table<TYPE>{

    struct Record<TYPE> *table;

public:
```

Problem comes when I try to put date inside those records. My strcpy gives me "Access violation writing location". (All elements of Records array initialized in class constructor):

```
template <class TYPE>
bool SimpleTable<TYPE>::update(const char* key, const TYPE& value){
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        if (table[i].key == ""){
            strcpy(table[i].key , key); // <-------- crash right here
            table[i].value = value;
        }
    }
        return true;
}
```

Comment: `char* key=new char();` allocates a single char. `char* key=new char[10];` allocates an array as you need there. `key = other.key;` in the assignment operator is also wrong.

Comment: you allocate a single character then proceed to copy an entire string on top of it, what did you expect?

Comment: Please don't capitalize C identifier that are actually in lower case (your title had `Strcpy` rather than `strcpy` before I edited it). There could easily be another function called `Strcpy`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char* key=new char();
```

only allocates memory to hold one character.

```
strcpy(table[i].key , key);
```

will lead to undefined behavior unless `key` is an empty string.

Use `std::string key`. If you are not allowed to use `std::string`, you'll have to revisit your code and fix memory issues related to `key`.

Comment: Also, `key = "default";` throws away the pointer to the character you allocated and replaces it with a pointer to a constant. You can't modify a constant, so now `key` points to something you can't modify. So trying to copy into it will fail. (To copy something into what a pointer points to, the pointer must point to something you can modify.)